# Writing web application code for a Weblogic Cluster

Tags: cluster-computing

I have a standard web application deployed to an application server.
The application uses Struts 1, iBatis, JSP, Servlets, pretty basic stuff.

Now the application will be deployed to a Weblogic cluster. Is there anything in particular I need to rework so that the application may be deployed to a cluster, for instance, how about transactions? 
Or is deploying to a cluster invisible to the developer?
Looking for general things to look into, things that for sure need to be done when a web application is deployed to a cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend minimizing session data.  Session data either forces a user to be "sticky" (once they use one particular server they have to keep going there) or the clustering software has to replicate all sessions to all servers.

Think hard about thread safety.  You don't want a situation where one user can ever see another's private data.

Also look at you database isolation.  You have to strike the right balance between serializable transactions and performance.

Comment: about transactions...say i have a transaction that involves multiple inserts and deletes. what happens if, in the middle of the transaction, the server fails, does another server in the cluster pick up where left off, and just completes, sort of invisible to me?

Comment: app server cluster and database server cluster are two separate things, assuming that you aren't running the database on the app server.  Best to consult your database docs.